In which direction does the iron piece experience force in this electromagnet setup?
Given a U shaped electromagnet and an iron piece setup as shown below:

We can assume the electromagnet is fixed.
When the electromagnet is energized, in which direction will the iron piece experience force? For a U shaped iron piece of same size and shape as the electromagnet, placed end to end with the electromagnet, the force would be in the vertical direction. Would it be the case in this setup too?
Secondly, will the magnitude of force change radically as compared to a U shaped iron piece placed end to end at a distance of 1 mm from the electromagnet? We can assume the distance between the two is negligible (say 1 mm) in the second case, too.

The iron piece will shift upwards to roughly this position: -

It will attempt to minimize the magnetic reluctance path.

will the magnitude of force change radically as compared to a U shaped
iron piece placed end to end at a distance of 1 mm from the
electromagnet?

The force will change as the iron piece moves upwards and, will become lowest at the position shown above. If gravity isn't a factor then the force will be largely zero at the position above. If gravity is a factor then there will be a force on the iron piece equivalent to the weight of the iron piece and, of course, the iron piece will be slightly lower than what I've shown above.

I am a bit confused. Why wouldn't force increase as the iron piece move upwards (as it happens in the case when two magnets are brought closer, the force b/w them increases)? And what is the rate of decrease of force with distance?

As the iron piece moves upwards, the magnetic field lines "prefer" to flow through the higher-permeability iron parts (e.g., the core of the electromagnet) rather than the air gap.
When the iron piece reaches the position where it aligns vertically (as in your diagram), the reluctance path becomes more efficient without significant additional pulling force. Essentially, the system "settles" at this position because it is a point of minimal energy and minimal reluctance.
The force decreases approximately with the square of the distance

@TheoryQuest1 if the force kept on increasing then when could there ever be an equilibrium position for the iron piece. Two magnets brought together can never physically have an equilibrium position without occupying the same physical space (which they cannot because they are solid). The iron piece as drawn is different because it can find a position where forces can cancel out.

@Andyaka I am still confused with the doubt. When I say force I mean the following: If I have to stop the magnet from moving further at any time $$t_i$$ at its current position $$p_i$$ the amount of downwards force we require to do so at that time $t_i$. Now, wouldn't the force in this sense increase as iron piece moves upwards? How can the force decrease as the other comment suggested. And going by this definition the maximum force would be when the iron piece has traveled and reaches the position that you depicted in your image?

As I understand that as the iron piece moves vertically more and more field lines pass though the point of contact b/w magnet and iron piece (since this path becomes shorter). But the doubt I have is that: "Won't these field lines that pass though iron piece ends exert any 'vertical pull' to it"?

What magnet are you talking about? Regarding the iron piece, it's impossible to tell what your question specifically is from your comments so, I suggest you make a new post and ask a brand-new question. Apart from anything else it opens up your queries to the whole floor and that has to be good news for you. @TheoryQuest1

It will do something like this as it attempts to minimise the magnetic resistance of the path through the electromagnet coil.

The system is metastable and will tend to go out of alignment to find a local minimum such as above, and then ordinary friction will take over and it will stop moving.
But if you pulse the electromagnet just right you may be able to get the legs to stick to the bottom of the channel.

This is a global minimum, and again friction will prevent further movement.

That's clever thinking and deserves upvoting.

Even the configuration in your second diagram doesn't seem stable. It will shift to left or right until the walls touch.

possibly, but the walls won't touch because the curve in the bottom corner.

@JasenСлаваУкраїні Thank you. I understand the answer. But I still have doubts? Doubt 1: When the iron piece moves from the initial position would it move vertically in a single direction or in a haphazard way till it reaches the final position as you described? The other answer seems to suggest the latter (if i understood correctly) but now i am doubtful? If it does can the iron piece be put on a metal rail so that it moves only in single direction (vertically)?

Your electromagnet has legs of different lengths, this alone will be enough to cause the C to start rotating as it starts moving up. but even without it, the midde position is metastable point, moving to either side will lead to a stronger force in that direction
